# Adding Nested Treeview Nodes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I am trying to add some items to a TreeView Control:

```
    TV1.Nodes.Add("key1", "Test1")  'Works
    TV1.Nodes("key1").Nodes.Add("key2", "Test2") 'Works (Nested)
    TV1.Nodes("key2").Nodes.Add("key3", "Test3") 'Error (NullReferenceException)
```

any ideas? thanks :)

Comment: see this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382928/how-to-add-nodes-to-a-wpf-treelist-using-vb-net-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
    TV1.Nodes.Add("key1", "Test1")
    TV1.Nodes.Find("key1", True)(0).Nodes.Add("key2", "Test2")
    TV1.Nodes.Find("key2", True)(0).Nodes.Add("key3", "Test3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the structure you want looks like:

```
key1
-- key2
   -- key3
```

the final line should be:
`TV1.Nodes("key1").Nodes("key2").Nodes.Add("key3", "Test3")`

Or with

```
key1
-- key2
-- key3
```

Use `TV1.Nodes("key1").Nodes.Add("key3", "Test3")`

Comment: thanks Tom - what I need is the first solution. But is there a more simpler way? If the Tree node consists of hundreds nested items, is there a way to add a child using the key of the parent?

Comment: No worries! Ideally you'd use a recursive routine to load the treeview by passing in the "parent" node returned from the Add function. This way you'd only ever need to say `parent.Add(data, text)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Test
  Dim CurrentNode As TreeNode

  Private Sub Search_and_Add(CurrentNode As TreeNode, NodesListArray() As String, Pointer As Integer)
    If Pointer >= NodesListArray.Length Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim BasisNodeExists As Integer = 0
    Dim BasisNodeGID As Integer = 0

    If Pointer = 0 Then
      For j As Integer = 0 To TreeView1.Nodes.Count - 1
        If TreeView1.Nodes(j).Text = NodesListArray(j) Then
          BasisNodeExists = 1
          BasisNodeGID = j
        End If
      Next

      If BasisNodeExists = 1 Then
        Search_and_Add(TreeView1.Nodes.Item(BasisNodeGID), NodesListArray, Pointer + 1)
      Else
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(NodesListArray(Pointer)))
        Search_and_Add(TreeView1.Nodes.Item(0), NodesListArray, Pointer + 1)
      End If
    Else
      Dim NewEntryRequired As Integer = 1
      For i As Integer = 0 To CurrentNode.Nodes.Count - 1
        If CurrentNode.Nodes.Item(i).Text = NodesListArray(Pointer) Then
          NewEntryRequired = 0
        End If
      Next
      If NewEntryRequired = 1 Then
        CurrentNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(NodesListArray(Pointer)))
      End If
      For i As Integer = 0 To CurrentNode.Nodes.Count - 1
        If CurrentNode.Nodes.Item(i).Text = NodesListArray(Pointer) Then
          Search_and_Add(CurrentNode.Nodes.Item(i), NodesListArray, Pointer + 1)
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Search_and_Add(New TreeNode(), New String() {"1", "2", "3"}, 0)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.parent.aspx

You can make it even simpler - Just use the IsNot check and go ahead to add if the parent node exists.

BlueColorMan

Comment: Linking to material on the web is fine, but would you provide a simple example in the answer please?